# Forcing bootstrap validation on "next" button before moving to the next tab

Tags: forms, validation, button, tabs, preventdefault

I would like to force the user to fill out all required fields on the current Form before moving to the next tab by clicking on a "next" button. I am using Bootstrap form Validation. Every "next" button is contained in its own Form. The problems I am facing are the following:

1- even when the required fields are still empty on the current Form, the click on the "NEXT" button proceeds to the next tab, even though the Form Validation failed. Which means the **event.preventDefault()** and  **event.stopPropagation()** are not stopping the user to move to the next tab. To try to solve this issue, I put the code inside **$(document).ready(function()** as I read somewhere that it would fix the issue, but it did not.

2- Once on the next tab, I still cannot grab the current Form inside the variable I call "form". For some reasons, the variable form only holds the very first Form, even after moving to the next tab.

Can someone points me to the right direction? Below is a snippet of my HTML code and my script.  Thank you for your help.

```
<p>Requestor Information</p>

 <!--This form allows the user to provide information about his profile-->
 <form class="need-validation-for-requestor-data" id="RequestorTabDataForm" novalidate>
      <div style="margin-left:12px">
           <div class="form-row">

 <!---Some more stuff here--->


 <!---Some more stuff here--->

           </div>

 <!---Some more stuff here--->

      </div>

      <a href="#" role="button" id="previousBtnProjectInformation"class="btn btn-secondary btn-tab-prev">Previous</a>
      <a href="#" role="button" id="nextBtnProjectInformation"class="btn btn-secondary btn-tab-next">Next</a>


 </form>



 <script>


   $('.btn-tab-prev').on('click', function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        $('#' + $('.nav-item > .active').parent().prev().find('a').attr('id')).tab('show');

   });




 $('.btn-tab-next').on('click', function (e) {

            // Fetch current form to apply custom Bootstrap validation


         var form = $('#' + $('.btn-tab-next').parent().find('form').attr('id'));    // Pass the current form on click...

      if (form[0].checkValidity() === false) {  //If the validation failed... 
           e.preventDefault();   //prevent the user to move to next tab...
           e.stopPropagation();   

      };

      form.addClass('was-validated');  //until all required fields are filled out


       $('#' + $('.nav-item > .active').parent().next().find('a').attr('id')).tab('show');  //then the user can move to the next Tab

   })   


 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am able to do the form validation on the first tab (first form) only, but I still cannot do the validation on the next tab (next form). The reason is that I am still not able to grab the current form, after I did the validation on the very first one.  So right now, i am still trying to figure out how to grab the current form at anytime, and use that form for form validation.

```
 (function () {
        $('.btn-tab-prev').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#' + $('.nav-item > .active').parent().prev().find('a').attr('id')).tab('show');
        })
        var isFormValidated = true;

        $('.btn-tab-next').on('click', function (e) {

            // Fetch form to apply custom Bootstrap validation              
            var form = $('#' + $('.btn-tab-next').parent().find('form').attr('id'));



            if (form[0].checkValidity() === true) {

               e.preventDefault();
                $('#' + $('.nav-item > .active').parent().next().find('a').attr('id')).tab('show');
            };

            if (form[0].checkValidity() === false) {
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
                isFormValidated = false;

            };
             form.addClass('was-validated');



            if (isFormValidated === false) {  //This block forces the page to stay on the validation first, before we can move to next page

                return;
            };

            if (isFormValidated === true) {
                alert("test 2");
                $('.btn-tab-next').addClass('enabled');
            };


        });

  })();
```